# Efficiently creating many instances of a winrt metro control

Tags: c#, .net, performance, xaml, microsoft-metro

I want to be able to create a few hundred instances of a winrt control (a search result control) in a C# project. The problem is that doing so takes too long (tenths of a second or worse) and must be done on the UI thread, creating stalls and delays in showing results.

For now I've bypassed the issue by pre-caching many instance of the control during startup. This approach works, but affects the startup time (profiling shows 40% of processor time near startup is spent caching these controls) and creates details to be managed, like the size of the cache.

I think the issue is that every time the control is instantiated redundant work, like re-parsing XAML, is done by the underlying framework. Maybe there's a way to avoid repeating this work? Maybe I can cheaply clone an existing control? Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?

Comment: @joe_coolish I ended up implementing my own UI virtualization. I've added a self answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forenote: it's been awhile so Microsoft may have fixed the win8 app UI virtualization by now. I haven't checked.

What I ended up doing at the time was just hacking together my own UI virtualization to work around the issue. Basically: caching controls and re-using them to display the viewable data (using a binary search tree to efficiently query what can be seen). I wrote a [blog post about it](http://twistedoakstudios.com/blog/Post1007_working-around-the-brittle-ui-virtualization-in-windows-8).

Answer (score 1):

- You could do the pre-caching in a parallel thread. Will make less of an impact on startup time on multicore processors
- searchresult.memberwiseclone wil give you shallow copies. It might be faster, not sure
- Could you use just one searchresult and fill it with the right data just before use? In that case there is no need to create a lot. Just use one as a re-usable container.
- If the time is spent when adding the controls to the parent forms you could use

  - suspendlayout/resumelayout (this is win32)
  - setting parent to invisible and back to visible when you are done
- Is there another way to do the same things faster? (competing control, 3d party etc)

Comment: 1) Can't safely construct controls in a non-ui thread. However, I do yield after each to allow other things to advance. 2) There's no MemberwiseClone function? 3) I need to show many. This is essentially the pre-caching strategy with size 1. 4) The time is spent in the control's constructor before being added to anything, so I don't expect layout to be the issue.

Comment: 2) Listed as method on base Object in .NET Would have expected it

Comment: I understand, but memberwiseclone is so lowlevel I'd have expected it to be included.